# User authentication and authorization for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Excuse my lack of knowledge, 
Lately, I am learning rails and found it extremely easy and fun, but still there is alot to learn.

I made an application for managing a Car workshop:

Owners has many cars 
cars has many visits
visits belong to a car and an owner.

I wanna have the ability for diffrent users of workshops to manage their businesses, what is the currect design in order to make visits and cars and owners belong to that specific user, is making all models belong to User enough? where can I read about this? managing access to dabases based on the logged in user?

I read about authentication, but its not answering my question, which is the best design for my needs, which is workshops managing only their data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably check Devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) which is one of the most common ways of handling authentication

In the end, you will have a User model and then you can treat it as any other model, so for example if you only want to show a user's cars you could do something like `current_user.cars` and restrict certain controller actions to happen only if `user_signed_in?` and so on. I do recommend checking their documentation, since most use cases are explained easily.

Answer (score 1):

Devise can be used to handle authentication and Pundit or CanCanCan can be used for authorization. I'd recommend looking at those, there are many tutorials which will answer your question for those.